# How new string(Char[]) works in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm studing C# for two weeks. And I have problem, I don't know how 4th line of this code works, namely `new string(charArray)`

```
string s = "Hello";
char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(charArray);
Console.WriteLine(new string(charArray));
```

Thank you all for responding!

Comment: Can you be more specific? It creates a new string instance with the content of the character array. (It's basically the inverse of `ToCharArray()`)

Comment: @knittl i'm sorry, i meant 4th string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new` keyword means we are calling a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char())) for the `string` type, specifically one that expects a `char[]` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

> `string s = "Hello";`

This creates a new string, “Hello” assigned to a variable `s`

> `char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();`

This takes each character in the string `s` and puts it into an array: `[ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' ]`

> `Array.Reverse(charArray);`

This takes the array and reverses the contents: `[ 'o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'H' ]`. This does the operation in memory to the array itself so you don’t need to reassign it.

> `Console.WriteLine(new string(charArray));`

This is doing two things:
Assigning a new string that will contain each character in the array and then that value is being passed into Console.WriteLine which will write to the console output stream:

> `olleH`

You could break that up into two statements for clarity:

```cs
string s = new string(charArray);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```